# Unhandled exception in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll

Tags: nuget, azure-service-runtime

My project was working fine then I ran the debug after a break and I am getting the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents.dll' or one of its dependencies. The filename or extension is too long
```